# Opencart Fancybox product title

Tags: fancybox, opencart

I am using opencart 1.5.6 ,I installed a responsive custom Opencart template but i have an issue with product title in fancybox on product page. If i put only one basic image on my product without any additional images i can't see my product title. But on the other hand if my product has additional images then it works correctly.

Here is code from fancybox for basic image:

```
<div class="fancybox-skin" style="padding: 15px; width: auto; height: auto;">
<div class="fancybox-outer">
<a class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;" title="Close"></a>
```

And this is code when i use additional images:

```
<div class="fancybox-skin" style="padding: 15px; width: auto; height: auto;">
<div class="fancybox-outer">
<div class="fancybox-title fancybox-title-float-wrap">
<a class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;" title="Close"></a>
```

its seems that tittle is enabled only if i have additional images.

My question is how to add this title for basic image as well?

Here is code from fancybox.js(it's one part i couldn't post it all)

```
            scrollOutside : !0,
            index : 0,
            type : null,
            href : null,
            content : null,
            title : null,
            tpl : {
                wrap : '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>',
                image : '<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" />',
                iframe : '<iframe id="fancybox-frame{rnd}" name="fancybox-frame{rnd}" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen' +
                (f.browser.msie ? ' allowtransparency="true"' : "") + "></iframe>",
                error : '<p class="fancybox-error">The requested content cannot be loaded.<br/>Please try again later.</p>',
                closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>',
                next : '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
                prev : '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
            },
            openEffect : "fade",
            openSpeed : 250,
            openEasing : "swing",
            openOpacity : !0,
            openMethod : "zoomIn",
            closeEffect : "fade",
            closeSpeed : 250,
            closeEasing : "swing",
            closeOpacity : !0,
            closeMethod : "zoomOut",
            nextEffect : "elastic",
            nextSpeed : 250,
            nextEasing : "swing",
            nextMethod : "changeIn",
            prevEffect : "elastic",
            prevSpeed : 250,
            prevEasing : "swing",
            prevMethod : "changeOut",
            helpers : {
                overlay : !0,
                title : !0
            },
            onCancel : f.noop,
            beforeLoad : f.noop,
            afterLoad : f.noop,
            beforeShow : f.noop,
            afterShow : f.noop,
            beforeChange : f.noop,
            beforeClose : f.noop,
            afterClose : f.noop
        },
        group : {},
        opts : {},
        previous : null,
        coming : null,
        current : null,
        isActive : !1,
        isOpen : !1,
        isOpened : !1,
        wrap : null,
        skin : null,
        outer : null,
        inner : null,
        player : {
            timer : null,
            isActive : !1
        },
        ajaxLoad : null,
        imgPreload : null,
        transitions : {},
        helpers : {},
        open : function (a, d) {
            if (a && (f.isPlainObject(d) || (d = {}), !1 !== b.close(!0)))
                return f.isArray(a) || (a = s(a) ? f(a).get() : [a]), f.each(a, function (e, c) {
                    var j = {},
                    g,
                    h,
                    i,
                    l,
                    k;
                    "object" === f.type(c) && (c.nodeType && (c = f(c)), s(c) ? (j = {
                                href : c.data("fancybox-href") || c.attr("href"),
                                title : c.data("fancybox-title") || c.attr("title"),
                                isDom : !0,
                                element : c
                            }, f.metadata && f.extend(!0,
                                j, c.metadata())) : j = c);
                    g = d.href || j.href || (p(c) ? c : null);
                    h = d.title !== q ? d.title : j.title || "";
                    l = (i = d.content || j.content) ? "html" : d.type || j.type;
                    !l && j.isDom && (l = c.data("fancybox-type"), l || (l = (l = c.prop("class").match(/fancybox\.(\w+)/)) ? l[1] : null));
                    p(g) && (l || (b.isImage(g) ? l = "image" : b.isSWF(g) ? l = "swf" : "#" === g.charAt(0) ? l = "inline" : p(c) && (l = "html", i = c)), "ajax" === l && (k = g.split(/\s+/, 2), g = k.shift(), k = k.shift()));
                    i || ("inline" === l ? g ? i = f(p(g) ? g.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, "") : g) : j.isDom && (i = c) : "html" === l ? i = g : !l && (!g &&
                                j.isDom) && (l = "inline", i = c));
                    f.extend(j, {
                        href : g,
                        type : l,
                        content : i,
                        title : h,
                        selector : k
                    });
                    a[e] = j
                }), b.opts = f.extend(!0, {}, b.defaults, d), d.keys !== q && (b.opts.keys = d.keys ? f.extend({}, b.defaults.keys, d.keys) : !1), b.group = a, b._start(b.opts.index)
        },
        cancel : function () {
            var a = b.coming;
            a && !1 !== b.trigger("onCancel") && (b.hideLoading(), b.ajaxLoad && b.ajaxLoad.abort(), b.ajaxLoad = null, b.imgPreload && (b.imgPreload.onload = b.imgPreload.onerror = null), a.wrap && a.wrap.stop(!0, !0).trigger("onReset").remove(), b.coming = null, b.current ||
                b._afterZoomOut(a))
        },
        close : function (a) {
            b.cancel();
            !1 !== b.trigger("beforeClose") && (b.unbindEvents(), b.isActive && (!b.isOpen || !0 === a ? (f(".fancybox-wrap").stop(!0).trigger("onReset").remove(), b._afterZoomOut()) : (b.isOpen = b.isOpened = !1, b.isClosing = !0, f(".fancybox-item, .fancybox-nav").remove(), b.wrap.stop(!0, !0).removeClass("fancybox-opened"), b.transitions[b.current.closeMethod]())))
        },
        play : function (a) {
            var d = function () {
                clearTimeout(b.player.timer)
            },
            e = function () {
                d();
                b.current && b.player.isActive && (b.player.timer =
                        setTimeout(b.next, b.current.playSpeed))
            },
            c = function () {
                d();
                f("body").unbind(".player");
                b.player.isActive = !1;
                b.trigger("onPlayEnd")
            };
            if (!0 === a || !b.player.isActive && !1 !== a) {
                if (b.current && (b.current.loop || b.current.index < b.group.length - 1))
                    b.player.isActive = !0, f("body").bind({
                        "afterShow.player onUpdate.player" : e,
                        "onCancel.player beforeClose.player" : c,
                        "beforeLoad.player" : d
                    }), e(), b.trigger("onPlayStart")
            } else
                c()
        },
        next : function (a) {
            var d = b.current;
            d && (p(a) || (a = d.direction.next), b.jumpto(d.index + 1, a, "next"))
        },
        prev : function (a) {
            var d = b.current;
            d && (p(a) || (a = d.direction.prev), b.jumpto(d.index - 1, a, "prev"))
        },
        jumpto : function (a, d, e) {
            var c = b.current;
            c && (a = k(a), b.direction = d || c.direction[a >= c.index ? "next" : "prev"], b.router = e || "jumpto", c.loop && (0 > a && (a = c.group.length + a % c.group.length), a %= c.group.length), c.group[a] !== q && (b.cancel(), b._start(a)))
        },
        reposition : function (a, d) {
            var e = b.current,
            c = e ? e.wrap : null,
            j;
            c && (j = b._getPosition(d), a && "scroll" === a.type ? (delete j.position, c.stop(!0, !0).animate(j, 200)) : (c.css(j), e.pos = f.extend({},
                            e.dim, j)))
        },
        update : function (a) {
            var d = a && a.type,
            e = !d || "orientationchange" === d;
            e && (clearTimeout(u), u = null);
            b.isOpen && !u && (u = setTimeout(function () {
                        var c = b.current;
                        c && !b.isClosing && (b.wrap.removeClass("fancybox-tmp"), (e || "load" === d || "resize" === d && c.autoResize) && b._setDimension(), "scroll" === d && c.canShrink || b.reposition(a), b.trigger("onUpdate"), u = null)
                    }, e && !n ? 0 : 300))
        },
        toggle : function (a) {
            b.isOpen && (b.current.fitToView = "boolean" === f.type(a) ? a : !b.current.fitToView, n && (b.wrap.removeAttr("style").addClass("fancybox-tmp"),
                    b.trigger("onUpdate")), b.update())
        },
        hideLoading : function () {
            m.unbind(".loading");
            f("#fancybox-loading").remove()
        },
        showLoading : function () {
            var a,
            d;
            b.hideLoading();
            a = f('<div id="fancybox-loading"><div></div></div>').click(b.cancel).appendTo("body");
            m.bind("keydown.loading", function (a) {
                if (27 === (a.which || a.keyCode))
                    a.preventDefault(), b.cancel()
            });
            b.defaults.fixed || (d = b.getViewport(), a.css({
                    position : "absolute",
                    top : 0.5 * d.h + d.y,
                    left : 0.5 * d.w + d.x
                }))
        },
        getViewport : function () {
            var a = b.current && b.current.locked ||
                !1,
            d = {
                x : r.scrollLeft(),
                y : r.scrollTop()
            };
            a ? (d.w = a[0].clientWidth, d.h = a[0].clientHeight) : (d.w = n && B.innerWidth ? B.innerWidth : r.width(), d.h = n && B.innerHeight ? B.innerHeight : r.height());
            return d
        },
        unbindEvents : function () {
            b.wrap && s(b.wrap) && b.wrap.unbind(".fb");
            m.unbind(".fb");
            r.unbind(".fb")
        },
        bindEvents : function () {
            var a = b.current,
            d;
            a && (r.bind("orientationchange.fb" + (n ? "" : " resize.fb") + (a.autoCenter && !a.locked ? " scroll.fb" : ""), b.update), (d = a.keys) && m.bind("keydown.fb", function (e) {
                    var c = e.which || e.keyCode,
                    j =
                        e.target || e.srcElement;
                    if (27 === c && b.coming)
                        return !1;
                    !e.ctrlKey && (!e.altKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.metaKey && (!j || !j.type && !f(j).is("[contenteditable]"))) && f.each(d, function (d, j) {
                        if (1 < a.group.length && j[c] !== q)
                            return b[d](j[c]), e.preventDefault(), !1;
                        if (-1 < f.inArray(c, j))
                            return b[d](), e.preventDefault(), !1
                    })
                }), f.fn.mousewheel && a.mouseWheel && b.wrap.bind("mousewheel.fb", function (d, c, j, g) {
                    for (var h = f(d.target || null), i = !1; h.length && !i && !h.is(".fancybox-skin") && !h.is(".fancybox-wrap"); )
                        i = h[0] && !(h[0].style.overflow &&
                                "hidden" === h[0].style.overflow) && (h[0].clientWidth && h[0].scrollWidth > h[0].clientWidth || h[0].clientHeight && h[0].scrollHeight > h[0].clientHeight), h = f(h).parent();
                    if (0 !== c && !i && 1 < b.group.length && !a.canShrink) {
                        if (0 < g || 0 < j)
                            b.prev(0 < g ? "down" : "left");
                        else if (0 > g || 0 > j)
                            b.next(0 > g ? "up" : "right");
                        d.preventDefault()
                    }
                }))
        },
        trigger : function (a, d) {
            var e,
            c = d || b.coming || b.current;
            if (c) {
                f.isFunction(c[a]) && (e = c[a].apply(c, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)));
                if (!1 === e)
                    return !1;
                c.helpers && f.each(c.helpers, function (d,
                        e) {
                    e && (b.helpers[d] && f.isFunction(b.helpers[d][a])) && (e = f.extend(!0, {}, b.helpers[d].defaults, e), b.helpers[d][a](e, c))
                });
                f.event.trigger(a + ".fb")
            }
        },
        isImage : function (a) {
            return p(a) && a.match(/(^data:image\/.*,)|(\.(jp(e|g|eg)|gif|png|bmp|webp)((\?|#).*)?$)/i)
        },
        isSWF : function (a) {
            return p(a) && a.match(/\.(swf)((\?|#).*)?$/i)
        },
        _start : function (a) {
            var d = {},
            e,
            c,
            a = k(a);
            e = b.group[a] || null;
            if (!e)
                return !1;
            d = f.extend(!0, {}, b.opts, e);
            e = d.margin;
            c = d.padding;
            "number" === f.type(e) && (d.margin = [e, e, e, e]);
            "number" === f.type(c) &&
            (d.padding = [c, c, c, c]);
            d.modal && f.extend(!0, d, {
                closeBtn : !1,
                closeClick : !1,
                nextClick : !1,
                arrows : !1,
                mouseWheel : !1,
                keys : null,
                helpers : {
                    overlay : {
                        closeClick : !1
                    }
                }
            });
            d.autoSize && (d.autoWidth = d.autoHeight = !0);
            "auto" === d.width && (d.autoWidth = !0);
            "auto" === d.height && (d.autoHeight = !0);
            d.group = b.group;
            d.index = a;
            b.coming = d;
            if (!1 === b.trigger("beforeLoad"))
                b.coming = null;
            else {
                c = d.type;
                e = d.href;
                if (!c)
                    return b.coming = null, b.current && b.router && "jumpto" !== b.router ? (b.current.index = a, b[b.router](b.direction)) : !1;
                b.isActive =
                    !0;
                if ("image" === c || "swf" === c)
                    d.autoHeight = d.autoWidth = !1, d.scrolling = "visible";
                "image" === c && (d.aspectRatio = !0);
                "iframe" === c && n && (d.scrolling = "scroll");
                d.wrap = f(d.tpl.wrap).addClass("fancybox-" + (n ? "mobile" : "desktop") + " fancybox-type-" + c + " fancybox-tmp " + d.wrapCSS).appendTo(d.parent || "body");
                f.extend(d, {
                    skin : f(".fancybox-skin", d.wrap),
                    outer : f(".fancybox-outer", d.wrap),
                    inner : f(".fancybox-inner", d.wrap)
                });
                f.each(["Top", "Right", "Bottom", "Left"], function (a, b) {
                    d.skin.css("padding" + b, v(d.padding[a]))
                });
                b.trigger("onReady");
                if ("inline" === c || "html" === c) {
                    if (!d.content || !d.content.length)
                        return b._error("content")
                } else if (!e)
                    return b._error("href");
                "image" === c ? b._loadImage() : "ajax" === c ? b._loadAjax() : "iframe" === c ? b._loadIframe() : b._afterLoad()
            }
        },
        _error : function (a) {
            f.extend(b.coming, {
                type : "html",
                autoWidth : !0,
                autoHeight : !0,
                minWidth : 0,
                minHeight : 0,
                scrolling : "no",
                hasError : a,
                content : b.coming.tpl.error
            });
            b._afterLoad()
        },
        _loadImage : function () {
            var a = b.imgPreload = new Image;
            a.onload = function () {
                this.onload = this.onerror = null;
                b.coming.width =
                    this.width;
                b.coming.height = this.height;
                b._afterLoad()
            };
            a.onerror = function () {
                this.onload = this.onerror = null;
                b._error("image")
            };
            a.src = b.coming.href;
            !0 !== a.complete && b.showLoading()
        },
        _loadAjax : function () {
            var a = b.coming;
            b.showLoading();
            b.ajaxLoad = f.ajax(f.extend({}, a.ajax, {
                        url : a.href,
                        error : function (a, e) {
                            b.coming && "abort" !== e ? b._error("ajax", a) : b.hideLoading()
                        },
                        success : function (d, e) {
                            "success" === e && (a.content = d, b._afterLoad())
                        }
                    }))
        },
        _loadIframe : function () {
            var a = b.coming,
            d = f(a.tpl.iframe.replace(/\{rnd\}/g,
                        (new Date).getTime())).attr("scrolling", n ? "auto" : a.iframe.scrolling).attr("src", a.href);
            f(a.wrap).bind("onReset", function () {
                try {
                    f(this).find("iframe").hide().attr("src", "//about:blank").end().empty()
                } catch (a) {}

            });
            a.iframe.preload && (b.showLoading(), d.one("load", function () {
                    f(this).data("ready", 1);
                    n || f(this).bind("load.fb", b.update);
                    f(this).parents(".fancybox-wrap").width("100%").removeClass("fancybox-tmp").show();
                    b._afterLoad()
                }));
            a.content = d.appendTo(a.inner);
            a.iframe.preload || b._afterLoad()
        },
        _preloadImages : function () {
            var a =
                b.group,
            d = b.current,
            e = a.length,
            c = d.preload ? Math.min(d.preload, e - 1) : 0,
            f,
            g;
            for (g = 1; g <= c; g += 1)
                f = a[(d.index + g) % e], "image" === f.type && f.href && ((new Image).src = f.href)
        },
        _afterLoad : function () {
            var a = b.coming,
            d = b.current,
            e,
            c,
            j,
            g,
            h;
            b.hideLoading();
            if (a && !1 !== b.isActive)
                if (!1 === b.trigger("afterLoad", a, d))
                    a.wrap.stop(!0).trigger("onReset").remove(), b.coming = null;
                else {
                    d && (b.trigger("beforeChange", d), d.wrap.stop(!0).removeClass("fancybox-opened").find(".fancybox-item, .fancybox-nav").remove());
                    b.unbindEvents();
                    e = a.content;
                    c = a.type;
                    j = a.scrolling;
                    f.extend(b, {
                        wrap : a.wrap,
                        skin : a.skin,
                        outer : a.outer,
                        inner : a.inner,
                        current : a,
                        previous : d
                    });
                    g = a.href;
                    switch (c) {
                    case "inline":
                    case "ajax":
                    case "html":
                        a.selector ? e = f("<div>").html(e).find(a.selector) : s(e) && (e.data("fancybox-placeholder") || e.data("fancybox-placeholder", f('<div class="fancybox-placeholder"></div>').insertAfter(e).hide()), e = e.show().detach(), a.wrap.bind("onReset", function () {
                                    f(this).find(e).length && e.hide().replaceAll(e.data("fancybox-placeholder")).data("fancybox-placeholder",
                                        !1)
                                }));
                        break;
                    case "image":
                        e = a.tpl.image.replace("{href}", g);
                        break;
                    case "swf":
                        e = '<object id="fancybox-swf" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%"><param name="movie" value="' + g + '"></param>',
                        h = "",
                        f.each(a.swf, function (a, b) {
                            e += '<param name="' + a + '" value="' + b + '"></param>';
                            h += " " + a + '="' + b + '"'
                        }),
                        e += '<embed src="' + g + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%"' + h + "></embed></object>"
                    }
                    (!s(e) || !e.parent().is(a.inner)) && a.inner.append(e);
                    b.trigger("beforeShow");
                    a.inner.css("overflow", "yes" === j ? "scroll" : "no" === j ? "hidden" : j);
                    b._setDimension();
                    b.reposition();
                    b.isOpen = !1;
                    b.coming = null;
                    b.bindEvents();
                    if (b.isOpened) {
                        if (d.prevMethod)
                            b.transitions[d.prevMethod]()
                    } else
                        f(".fancybox-wrap").not(a.wrap).stop(!0).trigger("onReset").remove();
                    b.transitions[b.isOpened ? a.nextMethod : a.openMethod]();
                    b._preloadImages()
                }
        },
        _setDimension : function () {
            var a = b.getViewport(),
            d = 0,
            e = !1,
            c = !1,
            e = b.wrap,
            j = b.skin,
            g = b.inner,
            h = b.current,
            c = h.width,
            i = h.height,
            l = h.minWidth,
            t = h.minHeight,
            m = h.maxWidth,
            n = h.maxHeight,
            r = h.scrolling,
            p = h.scrollOutside ? h.scrollbarWidth : 0,
            w = h.margin,
            y = k(w[1] + w[3]),
            q = k(w[0] + w[2]),
            x,
            z,
            s,
            C,
            A,
            F,
            B,
            D,
            u;
            e.add(j).add(g).width("auto").height("auto").removeClass("fancybox-tmp");
            w = k(j.outerWidth(!0) - j.width());
            x = k(j.outerHeight(!0) - j.height());
            z = y + w;
            s = q + x;
            C = E(c) ? (a.w - z) * k(c) / 100 : c;
            A = E(i) ? (a.h - s) * k(i) / 100 : i;
            if ("iframe" === h.type) {
                if (u = h.content, h.autoHeight && 1 === u.data("ready"))
                    try {
                        u[0].contentWindow.document.location && (g.width(C).height(9999), F = u.contents().find("body"), p && F.css("overflow-x",
                                "hidden"), A = F.height())
                    } catch (G) {}

            } else if (h.autoWidth || h.autoHeight)
                g.addClass("fancybox-tmp"), h.autoWidth || g.width(C), h.autoHeight || g.height(A), h.autoWidth && (C = g.width()), h.autoHeight && (A = g.height()), g.removeClass("fancybox-tmp");
            c = k(C);
            i = k(A);
            D = C / A;
            l = k(E(l) ? k(l, "w") - z : l);
            m = k(E(m) ? k(m, "w") - z : m);
            t = k(E(t) ? k(t, "h") - s : t);
            n = k(E(n) ? k(n, "h") - s : n);
            F = m;
            B = n;
            h.fitToView && (m = Math.min(a.w - z, m), n = Math.min(a.h - s, n));
            z = a.w - y;
            q = a.h - q;
            h.aspectRatio ? (c > m && (c = m, i = k(c / D)), i > n && (i = n, c = k(i * D)), c < l && (c = l, i = k(c / D)), i < t &&
                (i = t, c = k(i * D))) : (c = Math.max(l, Math.min(c, m)), h.autoHeight && "iframe" !== h.type && (g.width(c), i = g.height()), i = Math.max(t, Math.min(i, n)));
            if (h.fitToView)
                if (g.width(c).height(i), e.width(c + w), a = e.width(), y = e.height(), h.aspectRatio)
                    for (; (a > z || y > q) && (c > l && i > t) && !(19 < d++); )
                        i = Math.max(t, Math.min(n, i - 10)), c = k(i * D), c < l && (c = l, i = k(c / D)), c > m && (c = m, i = k(c / D)), g.width(c).height(i), e.width(c + w), a = e.width(), y = e.height();
                else
                    c = Math.max(l, Math.min(c, c - (a - z))), i = Math.max(t, Math.min(i, i - (y - q)));
            p && ("auto" === r && i < A && c + w +
                p < z) && (c += p);
            g.width(c).height(i);
            e.width(c + w);
            a = e.width();
            y = e.height();
            e = (a > z || y > q) && c > l && i > t;
            c = h.aspectRatio ? c < F && i < B && c < C && i < A : (c < F || i < B) && (c < C || i < A);
            f.extend(h, {
                dim : {
                    width : v(a),
                    height : v(y)
                },
                origWidth : C,
                origHeight : A,
                canShrink : e,
                canExpand : c,
                wPadding : w,
                hPadding : x,
                wrapSpace : y - j.outerHeight(!0),
                skinSpace : j.height() - i
            });
            !u && (h.autoHeight && i > t && i < n && !c) && g.height("auto")
        },
        _getPosition : function (a) {
            var d = b.current,
            e = b.getViewport(),
            c = d.margin,
            f = b.wrap.width() + c[1] + c[3],
            g = b.wrap.height() + c[0] + c[2],
            c = {
                position : "absolute",
                top : c[0],
                left : c[3]
            };
            d.autoCenter && d.fixed && !a && g <= e.h && f <= e.w ? c.position = "fixed" : d.locked || (c.top += e.y, c.left += e.x);
            c.top = v(Math.max(c.top, c.top + (e.h - g) * d.topRatio));
            c.left = v(Math.max(c.left, c.left + (e.w - f) * d.leftRatio));
            return c
        },
        _afterZoomIn : function () {
            var a = b.current;
            a && (b.isOpen = b.isOpened = !0, b.wrap.css("overflow", "visible").addClass("fancybox-opened"), b.update(), (a.closeClick || a.nextClick && 1 < b.group.length) && b.inner.css("cursor", "pointer").bind("click.fb", function (d) {
                    !f(d.target).is("a") && !f(d.target).parent().is("a") &&
                    (d.preventDefault(), b[a.closeClick ? "close" : "next"]())
                }), a.closeBtn && f(a.tpl.closeBtn).appendTo(b.skin).bind(n ? "touchstart.fb" : "click.fb", function (a) {
                    a.preventDefault();
                    b.close()
                }), a.arrows && 1 < b.group.length && ((a.loop || 0 < a.index) && f(a.tpl.prev).appendTo(b.outer).bind("click.fb", b.prev), (a.loop || a.index < b.group.length - 1) && f(a.tpl.next).appendTo(b.outer).bind("click.fb", b.next)), b.trigger("afterShow"), !a.loop && a.index === a.group.length - 1 ? b.play(!1) : b.opts.autoPlay && !b.player.isActive && (b.opts.autoPlay =
                        !1, b.play()))
        },
        _afterZoomOut : function (a) {
            a = a || b.current;
            f(".fancybox-wrap").trigger("onReset").remove();
            f.extend(b, {
                group : {},
                opts : {},
                router : !1,
                current : null,
                isActive : !1,
                isOpened : !1,
                isOpen : !1,
                isClosing : !1,
                wrap : null,
                skin : null,
                outer : null,
                inner : null
            });
            b.trigger("afterClose", a)
        }
    });
    b.transitions = {
        getOrigPosition : function () {
            var a = b.current,
            d = a.element,
            e = a.orig,
            c = {},
            f = 50,
            g = 50,
            h = a.hPadding,
            i = a.wPadding,
            l = b.getViewport();
            !e && (a.isDom && d.is(":visible")) && (e = d.find("img:first"), e.length || (e = d));
            s(e) ? (c = e.offset(),
                e.is("img") && (f = e.outerWidth(), g = e.outerHeight())) : (c.top = l.y + (l.h - g) * a.topRatio, c.left = l.x + (l.w - f) * a.leftRatio);
            if ("fixed" === b.wrap.css("position") || a.locked)
                c.top -= l.y, c.left -= l.x;
            return c = {
                top : v(c.top - h * a.topRatio),
                left : v(c.left - i * a.leftRatio),
                width : v(f + i),
                height : v(g + h)
            }
        },
        step : function (a, d) {
    })
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

Comment: the fancybox `title` is added only if you have a `title` attribute in your anchor tag

Comment: yes i can see that ,but how to add this tittle ? (my mistake i didnt make clear what i wanted to achive)